# Did Daryl Van Horne participate in group sex with the three women?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-witches-of-eastwick

Daryl did seduce each of the women individually.  He started with Alex and moved on to Jane and he seduced Sukie last.  Alex and Jane were unaware of Daryl's intentions towards the two of them at first, but then just accepted his seduction of Sukie when the four of them were together.  We know that Daryl had sexual relations with each of the women on a one-on-one basis:

**Daryl's seduction of Alex:**

> **Daryl:**  No. I wouldn't dream of seducing you, Alexandra. I wouldn't insult your intelligence with anything as trivial as
> seduction. But I would love to fuck you.

**Daryl's seduction of Jane:**

> **Daryl:** Let it go. Let it fly. What are you afraid of? You have great passion in you. Let it out. I can take it. I want it.

**Daryl's seduction of Sukie:**

> **Sukie:**  Are you going to seduce me, too?
>
> **Daryl:**  Yes.

Daryl seduces the women individually, but they seem to always be together in Daryl's mansion.  There is gossip within the town, but to my knowledge, nothing is ever confirmed.  They merely just say that they are all friends and Daryl calls the women "his girls."

There is a scene when the women come back to him depicting the three of them lying on his bed in provocative positions suggesting that something like this might have taken place, but the scene quickly cuts to the next morning and nothing is mentioned of it:

[image]

**Is there any evidence that the three women actually have group sex with Daryl?**

Comment: "Is there any evidence" Er, *this picture*?! ;) Seriously, they're all waiting for him on the bed in sexy lingerie and beckon him in. And *he's the devil*. I reckon a foursome is the *least* debauched thing that went on there.

Comment: @Walt Ohhhh...really?  You think that there was more debauched things there?  Well, they were all in the same sort of seducing forms in the pool and he only went after Sukie...I don't know.

Comment: But that's different, they were just hanging out in the pool... But what other possible scenario can follow *this* tableau?! They all strike a seductive pose on the same bed, but two of them then awkwardly depart and await their turn in another room?

Comment: @Walt Yeah, because they did it before.  They show the four of them together and then the two of them (Daryl and Sukie) breaking off with one another.  The three women seem to carry on as they did before they were with Daryl, which, I'm sorry, but if you're involved in a threesome with your best friends, your relationship is going to change ;)

Comment: "relationship is going to change" That's an interesting point. But I just thought they were under his spell.

Comment: @Walt Good point.  I guess that they were kind of under his spell at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [source novel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witches_of_Eastwick) by John Updike makes it abundantly clear that all three women had sex with 'Van Horne' and sex with each other in this scene.

> When Joplin croaked "Summertime" at that broken tempo, remembering the words in impassioned spasms as if repeatedly getting up off the canvas in some internal drug-hazed prizefight, Sukie and Alexandra swayed in each other's arms without their feet moving, their fallen hair stringy and tangled with tears, their breasts touching, nuzzling, fumbling in pale pillow fight lubricated by drops of sweat worn on their chests like the broad bead necklaces of ancient Egypt. And when Joplin with that deceptively light-voiced opening drifted into the whirlpool of "Me and Bobby McGee," Van Horne, his empurpled penis rendered hideously erect by a service Jane had performed for him on her knees, pantomimed with his uncanny hands—encased it seemed in white rubber gloves with wigs of hair and wide at the tips like the digits of a tree toad or lemur—in the dark above her bobbing head the tumultuous solo provided by the inspired pianist of the Full Tilt Boogie band.
>
> On the black velour mattresses Van Horne had provided, the three women played with him together, using the parts of his body as a vocabulary with which to speak to one another; he showed supernatural control, and when he did come his semen, all agreed later, was marvellously cold.

Answer (score -4):

I think not, because as close as the three women are I don't see them as bi, I think that like Hugh Hefner he has a choosing of individual he has sex with